# How to execute Javascript for (not in) Ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a **one page responsive** portfolio site in Wordpress based on the Foundation framework by Zurb. I'm not happy with the Clearing lightbox included in the framework, so I'm trying to include a different lightbox for images/videos (currently using Magnific Popup [http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html], but I've tried a few different plugins, including Fancybox, Colorbox, and the Responsive Lightbox plugin from dFactory).

I have a custom post type called Projects.  All of the projects get displayed on the one page website, and when the user clicks on a project to see more information, the_content gets called and loaded into a div dynamically via Ajax (similar to the way portfolio projects work in the SimpleKey Wordpress theme [http://themeforest.net/item/simplekey-one-page-portfolio-wordpress-theme/3729774]).

I can get the lightbox to work on the single.php page if I manually navigate to it (ex. http://www.aisle7Studios/project/project-name/), however when I'm on the main one-page site, I can't get the lightbox to work. I know this is because the content is being loaded dynamically via Ajax, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Ideas?

**This is the Javascript that loads the portfolio posts, located in header.php**

```
<!-- Items for loading portfolio posts without refreshing -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $("h6 a").click(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel")
        $("#singlePortfolioPost").html("loading...");
        $("#singlePortfolioPost").load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/portfolio-item/",{id:post_id});
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<!-- End Portfolio Post load-->
```

**This is the div where the post content gets loaded, located on the Portfolio page.**

```
<div id="singlePortfolioPost" class="large-12">

</div> <!-- .singlePortfolioPost -->
```

The content loads fine, and upon examining the code, I can see that the plugins that automatically add **rel="lightbox"** to anchor tags work the way they're supposed to.  However the lightbox plugins just don't work...they simply take me to the media file I clicked on.

Comment: Bump...anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your point, let's see if i can help you. If you're working with the div dynamically (in the background) sounds like you'll have no problem to trigger the modal "open" event. Because it's DOM. What do you have in your browser console when you try to execute the process?